# Serve static files with X-Accel-Redirect with PHP on nginx

Tags: php, nginx, backend, x-accel-redirect

i have some files outside my root directory (/var/www/data) and would like to serve them over an URL e.g. https://example.com/data/?id=123456. I would use for this the X-Accel-Redirect header. My nginx configuration is the following:

```
server {

    server_name example.com;
    server_tokens off;
    root /var/www/html/;

    location / {
        index index.php index.html;
    }
    location ~ \.php(?:$|/) {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param MOD_X_ACCEL_REDIRECT_ENABLED on;
        fastcgi_param MOD_X_ACCEL_REDIRECT_PREFIX /data/;
    }

    location /data/ {
        internal;
        alias /var/www/data/;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; 
    ssl_certificate ...; 
    ssl_certificate_key ...;
    ssl_dhparam ...; 
}
```

Now I am trying to to serve the files on https://example.com/data/index.php like this:

```
$url = "/var/www/data/file.jpg;
header("X-Accel-Redirect: ".$url);
```

I get a 404 error and the nginx error log is the following:

```
[error] 8401#8401: *1 open() "/var/www/html/var/www/data/file.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: .....
```

Please help me to solve this issue!

Comment: Looking at your configuration, the URI for the internal location should be `/data/file.jpg` and **not** `/var/www/data/file.jpg`. Try: `$url = "/data/file.jpg;`

Comment: i tried that but than i get the following error: *1 open() "/var/www/html/data/file.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: ..... because thats not where the file is...

Comment: Do you have any other `location` blocks in your configuration - perhaps one that matches URIs ending with `.jpg`?

Comment: No, I do not. Is there another solution without X-Accel-Redirect?

Comment: It seems like php-fpm is considering /var/www/html/ as root and it's impossible to access anything outside?